# Google app script for getting the number of slides in a deck

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a simple script to get the number of slides in a Google slide deck. I'll incorporate it into a larger script where I'm extracting notes out of each slide and I want to be able to report progress -- e.g. Slide 5 of 25... --> I need to get the 25 (total slides in the deck) to do so.

Comment: See [Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides())

Comment: @thewized It looks like that returns the list of slides in a presentation. How would I get it to return the number of slides in the presentation? I've tried this code, and it seems to work, but is perhaps a little clunky? (I can't seem to get this to format as code in this comment)
`  
SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides().forEach((s, i) => {
totalSlides = totalSlides + 1;
});
Logger.log("totalSlides = " + totalSlides)
`

Comment: `Presentation.getSlides()` returns an array of slides simply get the `.length` of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following sample:

```js
function totalSlides() {
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides();

  for(i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
    Logger.log("Slide " + (i+1) + " of " + slides.length)
  }

  //If you only need the number of total slides, then you can use the following
  Logger.log("Total Slides: " + slides.length)
}
```